# design an error reporting utility

Tags: java

I had difficulties finding a relevant title since it is not a simple issue. I will try to explain. I have a class responsible of error reporting whose methods basically wrap multiple ways of reporting an error.
For example, I have a method failTest:

```
public static void failTest(Logger log, Exception e, String message, boolean reportToES, String esTestPath, String esTestSet, String esTestInstance)
{
log.error(e, message);
someExternalErrorReportingService(reportToES, esTestPath,esTestSet,esTestInstance);
Assert.fail(e,message);
}
```

And I call this error reporting method in many, many places and it doesn't seem a good practice (too many parameters, hard to follow their order etc.) to just call it with the es* parameters each and every time because they don't change very often so they could be set up once and then reused.
And I came up with this version

```
public static void failTest(Logger log, Exception e, String message)
{//same body
}
And then added method to set up es* parameters
setES(boolean reportToES, String esTestPath, String esTestSet, String esTestInstance)
{
this.reportToES = reportToES; 
this.esTestPath = esTestPath; 
this.esTestSet = esTestSet; 
this.esTestInstance=esTestInstance;
}
```

and of course added these instance variables above.
And only now I can enunciate the issue:
now if I want to use this error reporting class I need to first instantiate it and set the es* fields. The issue is that I often need to use the error reporting in a utility class that could be static but now, with my change above, I have to instantiate it and set up the error reporting class in order to have the es* fields set before I call failTest().
To conclude, I don't like this solution either because I can't use static utility classes anymore and moreover some utility classes are already used in a static way so cannot be refactored to non-static and will end up being used sometimes static, sometimes instantiated.
So the question is, do you see a better solution in order to simplify the calling of failTest() in utility classes?
To give you an example, we have a client that 
sets up the error reporting class and sets up its es* fields
This client calls utility method Utility.doSomething

```
public static doSomething(reportToES, esTestPath, esTestSet, esTestInstance)
{
try{
 methodThatThrowsFatalException()
}
catch(Exception e){
failTest(log, e, "Some smart message",reportToES, esTestPath, esTestSet, esTestInstance);
}
}
```

Now, in order to reduce the number of parameters we can just add setErrorReportingInstance to the Utility class,
then in client instantiate the Utility, then utilityInstance. setErrorReportingInstance(configuredErrorReportingInstance). And doSomething becomes:

```
public static doSomethingRefactored()
{
try{
 methodThatThrowsFatalException()
}
catch(Exception e){
errorReportingInstance.failTest(log, e, "Some smart message");
}
}
```

What is not ok, from my point of view, is that:
1. I have complicated the usage of Utility. Now I have to make sure it is instantiated before I use it. It's inconvenient when having a lot of Utility like classes. 
2. I cannot make static methods in Utility if I have to do error reporting in their implementation. 
3. The methods that are already used as static will remain with the es* parameters in their signature (due to backward compatibility). So I will have in the same class methods like doSomething and also methods like doSomethingRefactored.
4. I have created a dependency between utility classes and error reporting so I have an issue when I need to test the utility methods

The question is, how can I keep the simple design of utility classes as simple collection of static utility methods but in the same time use the error reporting class but without passing too many parameters since it is bad practice?

More details:
Actually the client is many TestNG test cases:
So first I had :

```
class TestClass1
{
static final boolean REPORT_TO_ES="true", 
static final String ES_TEST_PATH="somePath", //and so on for the others 
@Test
{
Utility1.doSomething(REPORT_TO_ES,ES_TEST_PATH,ES_TEST_SET,...
Utility2.doSomethingElse(REPORT_TO_ES,ES_TEST_PATH,ES_TEST_SET,...
Utility3.doSomethingMoreUseful(REPORT_TO_ES,ES_TEST_PATH,ES_TEST_SET,...
Utility4.doSomethingSomething(REPORT_TO_ES,ES_TEST_PATH,ES_TEST_SET,...
}
```

And then I would try to get rid of calling the doSomethings with the ES* values
by setting them once on the ErrorReporter instance (so I would also make ErrorReporter non-static).

```
class TestClass1
{
private ErrorReporter errorReporter = new ErrorReporter();
errorReporter.setReportToEs(true);
errorReporter.setEsTestPath("somePath");//and so on
Utility1 utility1Instance = new Utility1();
utility1Instance.setErrorReporter(errorReporter);
Utility2 utility1Instance = new Utility2();
utility2Instance.setErrorReporter(errorReporter);
@Test
{
utility1Instance.doSomething();
utility2Instance.doSomethingElse();
...
```

Comment: Combine all of the Es parameters into an Es object. You can pass that into doSomething().

Comment: If Utility is used for testing only (your last comment suggests this) then make the Utility be the Es object itself. It is not clear why you favor static methods in this case. I must admit I am having a hard time understanding the big picture. Why not post a complete source?

Comment: es variables are legacy code. We don't know right now if we would keep them or not. That's why I want to keep them in a central place so they would be removed completely if we decided we will never need them. But as always we can't have it all so combining Es parameters into an Es object seems a better solution that having 4 values

Answer (score 0):

The title to your question should be "Static Mess".

Take a look at how real loggers work and you may get some ideas. Log4J and Slf4j are well respected ones. You need to control all of your static variables. You could create a Logger class that encapsulates the ES data and does the real work of logging:

```
// Does the real work of logging.
class Logger {
   public Logger(all of your es data)
   public fail(String msg) // Logs msg
}
```

Then you need a static collection of these Loggers referenced by name (I assume you have more than one set of es data). This gives you a central place to go get the loggers. Works if you're in a static method or somewhere else. The static collection goes inside the LogFactory object

```
class LogFactory {
   private static Map<String, Logger> loggers ...
   public static Logger get(String name) ...
}
```

Here is your static method using the new logger:

```
public static doSomething() {
   try {
     methodThatThrowsFatalException()
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    LogFactory.get("Util").failTest(e, "Some smart message");
  }
}
```

I would add a clear or reset method to LogFactory so that you have a chance of writing JUnit tests for your code. For the same reason I would write a NullLogger (in which case you might want to pull out an interface that the NullLogger and the EsLogger can both implement.

You need to decide how to add Loggers to LogFactory. I suggest doing it in your main class. Resist the temptation to do it in a static initializer.

LogFactory could also be written so it holds a collection and not a static collection. You then just keep a static reference (a Singleton) to it. Just keep in mind that you'll want a way to clear the Singleton to make unit testing possible.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The trouble with your solution is that the utility class (that has the doSomething() method) does not know what logger to retrieve (e.g. "Util"). Only the client knows what es values are appropriate so the utility class still needs to be instantiated in order to be made aware of the logger name or es values set. I'm sorry I haven't mentioned this restriction before.

Comment: Help me understand. You need to set some global data before you call doSomething() in order for the failTest() to work correctly? In essence you are using the heap to bypass the stack?